# Leaflet plugins in Angular project

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have an angular project (Angular 13) where I use leaflet. In the package.json file, I have:

```
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
"leaflet.heat": "^0.2.0",
```

In my component, I import leaflet via

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

Everything works fine and L includes the classes/methods from leaflet-draw and leaflet.heat as well. However, I could not understand how they are imported to the project when I only import 'leaflet'. I know that leaflet plugins do not export anything and they only add their stuff to L namescape of leaflet.

I just want to learn how Leaflet plugins become available even if I only import leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess those plugins are listed as *dependencies* in your package.json, so `npm install` will load them as they are (supposed to be) required for your application to work.

Then the plugins may not export anything, but they do *extend* Leaflet classes. For example the draw plugin extends Control class as follows:

**Code**
(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/Control.Draw.js)

```
...
line 5: L.Control.Draw = L.Control.extend({
...
```

Therefore you can use the functionality without explicitly importing anything. This is the way Leaflet recommends to implement plugins. In their documentation they mention `Class.extend` but this now seem to work for `L.Control` as well (also for `Handler` and `Layer`).

**References**
https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html
https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#dependencies